# jQuery Ajax load and getScript

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, getscript

I'm trying to set up my site so that content in the main area is loaded via javascript (some pages take a while to render). However, I've run into a bit of a logical problem when using jQuery.load(), jQuery.getScript and jQuery.ajax().

I need to be able to load certain javascript files via getScript so that I can use these functions etc inside the loaded content.

- index.php - The main file being displayed (also contains #loading)
- js/script.js - The file containing the load code
- js/*.js - Several javascript files I need to be able to use inside #maincontent after the load
- load.php - The file being loaded into #maincontent

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
$('#maincontent').load('load.php', function() {
    $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
    $('#maincontent').fadeIn('slow');
});

$('#navigation li a').click(function() {
    $('#maincontent').fadeOut('fast');

    $.getScript('js/jquery.contextMenu-1.01.js');
    $.getScript('js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js');
    $.getScript('js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js');
    $.getScript('js/jquery.qtip-2.0.0.min.js');
    $.getScript('js/ajax.js');

    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'load.php',
        data: 'page=' + $(this).attr('rel'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
        },
        success: function(html) {
            $('#maincontent').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#maincontent').html(html);
        }
    });
});

$.getScript('js/jquery.contextMenu-1.01.js');
$.getScript('js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js');
$.getScript('js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js');
$.getScript('js/jquery.qtip-2.0.0.min.js');
$.getScript('js/ajax.js');
});
```

As you can see, I'm trying to load load.php first without any URL parameters and any interaction from the user. Although load.php is loaded correctly every time, the same can't be said for the javascript code. Sometimes it works, other times I have to refresh the page a few times before I get a clean console (no errors).

The errors in the console suggest to me that the js code isn't loaded properly before it is being used inside load.php. This is especially true if load.php takes a while (tested with PHP sleep(5) function).

Let me know if I need to clarify anything :)

Comment: If you're using jQuery to load your PHP, then you don't need to include it again via `getScript`.  I recommend loading all your javascript on page load and only adding content via load(), especially avoid re-including frameworks and plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't really load all of those scripts with getScript.  You will need some (or all?) of them every time, so why not just include them on the page.  In addition, since your'e using jquery to load jquery, I'm going to say you already have it included on the page.  So don't try to load it again.

Comment: I agree 100%. In addition, @John Doe can merge all scripts in one single file. Set a high expire date, so the script will be cached on subsequent page loads and visits

Comment: @kingjiv I actually tried doing that before I went with this approach. I don't get any errors in the console when loading everything in index.php and using the load/ajax function to load #maincontent, but I can't seem to get any of the javascript (slider, qtip, contextmenu etc) to work inside the loaded content either. Your response has led me to believe that this is the correct way to do it, I just have to figure out how to make the js work in the loaded content!

Comment: @kingjiv No errors. Just nothing works. I'll gladly post some updated code, if you'd like

Comment: If you could post some of the code that is not executing that might be helpful.  The js that is in load.php.

Comment: @kingjiv My bad. I thought you meant to include all the libraries in index.php. I've included the necessary libraries in index.php and load.php respectively now and everything works as it should. I might have to scratch my head for a while to figure out the best way to continue with this though. Seems like I need to load all the libraries atleast three times for one page. First index.php, then load.php and then another page for a modal window which will require js. Does this seem like a good course of action?

Comment: I think you should be able to just load all of them on index.  Just with the normal "<script src=..."

Comment: @kingjiv I was hoping that was the case, but it doesn't look like it. It could be my code though, so here's a pastebin of said js: http://pastebin.com/CLm6MGy7

Comment: On second try, I tried just including the libraries in index.php and leave ajax.js (the file I pasted) inside load.php. This works.

Comment: Okay, I see.  I thought ajax.js was just a library.  Now looking at it, it has some code in `$(document).ready`.  So that would have to be in load.php so that it would execute when load.php was loaded.  The others which are libraries can be put into the index.  So I think you're good to go.

Comment: I actually added a getScript(ajax.js) call in script.js on ajax load of load.php and it's working like a charm. Thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 5):

If the problem is the timing of the loads, you should consider using the latest version of jQuery with deferred behavior.

You could, for instance, do:

```
    var wait1 = $.getScript('js/jquery.contextMenu-1.01.js');
var wait2 = $.getScript('js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js');
var wait3 = $.getScript('js/jquery-ui-1.8.12.custom.min.js');
var wait4 = $.getScript('js/jquery.qtip-2.0.0.min.js');
var wait5 = $.getScript('js/ajax.js');
$.when(wait1, wait2, wait3, wait4, wait5).then(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url: 'load.php',
        data: 'page=' + $(this).attr('rel'),
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#loading').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
        },
        success: function(html) {
            $('#maincontent').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#maincontent').html(html);
        }
    });
}, function() { handleErrorsFunction()});
```

This will wait until all of the getScript calls return and then do the ajax call to load.php (or it will trigger the handleErrorsFunction() if one of the above fails).